# simplest way to create reactjs app in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, visual-studio, reactjs.net

I've been trying to create a ReactJS app in visual studio and I have found that the simplest way to create a Reactjs App is using **dotnet new react -o SampleApp** but it comes with to much code, components, etc.. is there any way that I just can create a Hello World app? or a blank Reactjs app?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has provided an awesome tool for that called **create-react-app**.

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Add plugins in VS Code for better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create an empty project in Visual Studio and then add the ReactJS Nuget Package.

See this for more details: https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html